# Python Image (PIL) library not resizing properly per kwargs

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Here is my code:

```
import Image
import sys
import json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    srcPath = args.get('srcPath')
    image = Image.open(srcPath)
    sizes = {}

    for variant_name, dimensions in args.get('sizes').items():
        if '%' in dimensions:
            sizes[variant_name] = image.size
        else:
            width = int(dimensions.split('x')[0])
            height = int(dimensions.split('x')[1])
            widthAndHeight = (width, height)
            sizes[variant_name] = widthAndHeight

    for key, val in sizes.items():
        imageName = key + '.' + srcPath.split('.')[1]
        convertedImage = image.resize(val, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(imageName)
        print 'done'
```

And I'm calling it with:

`python image.py '{"sizes":{"large":"200x150","orig":"100%x100%"},"srcPath":"/Users/bobcobb/Desktop/avocado.png"}'`

If the argument `100%x100%` is passed in, then I want to resize to the original size, otherwise, I want to resize to the passed in size. So the above code would generate 2 images (one original, the other 200x150).

Right now, it just saves the image as the original size for both. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the resized image is assigned to `convertedImage`, but you save the original `image` (at the new filename).

So changing this line

```
image.save(imageName)
```

into

```
convertedImage.save(imageName)
```

solves this problem.

Comment: You're welcome :) One more tip: Use the functions in  [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to build filesystem paths, don't use manual string concatentation / parsing. For example [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to split by path into base and extension, `os.path.abspath` to make the path absolute before any further processing (your script currently fails for `./image.png`), and `os.path.basename` and `os.path.join` to build the new destination path.